Why are mouse move events discarded when the page is busy?
See this Blazor fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/rckyjgd5
There is a red box on the page. It has handlers for "onmousemove" and "onclick" events. Each of these causes a count to increment. The values of the counts are shown on the page.
Also on the page are 4 buttons. These buttons cause a time-consuming calculation to occur, but they do it slightly differently. (If you have a much faster or slower machine than I am using then you might want to adjust the value of the NumberOfIterations property so that the calculation takes a suitable amount of time - a few seconds is ideal.)

The first button performs the calculation synchronously.
The second button is declared as an async function, but like the first one it actually performs the calculation synchronously, because it doesn't use the "await" keyword anywhere.
The third button is asynchronous. It occasionally calls Task.Yield() while the calculation is in progress.
The fourth button is asynchronous. It occasionally calls Task.Delay() with a small value.

The purpose of this fiddle was for my own learning, to explore how asynchronous code works in Blazor and how to interrupt time-consuming code so that the UI remains responsive. The fiddle is a little overdone for the question I am asking.
There is a behaviour I find strange here. If the calculation is started (with one of the first 3 buttons) and I move the mouse over the red square, the mouse move events that should occur while the calculation is taking place seem to be discarded. The count doesn't update either during the time the page is busy, or afterwards. However if the calculation is started and I click on the red square, the count updates after the calculation finishes. If I click on the red square 5 times while the calculation is running, then when it finishes, the count will jump by 5. So these events aren't being discarded - they are being delayed, but they do happen eventually.
The fact that the behaviour of the 3rd button appears identical to the first 2 is explained by answers posted to these 2 Stack Overflow questions (first, second).
If the calculation is started with the fourth button, and I move the mouse pointer over the red square, then the count of mouse move events updates sporadically. There are intervals in which the count will update as I move the mouse, and intervals in which the mouse events are "dropped". And if I click with the mouse, then the events will all happen, and not with too great a delay, but those that happen while the browser is busy are clumped together.
From these observations it seems like:

The mouse move events that happen while the browser is "busy" are simply discarded. It is as though they never happened.
The click events that happen while the browser is "busy" are queued, and they take effect as soon as the browser is no longer "busy".

Questions:

Why is there a difference between the behaviour for mouse move and click events?
Is it a consequence of how I have constructed the fiddle?
Is it a consequence of how the JavaScript execution model for browsers is supposed to work? (Either how it's supposed to work per relevant standards, or of how it happens to work in the browsers I tried this on?)
Is it a consequence of how WASM works? (Either how it's supposed to work per the standard, or of how it happens to work in the browsers I tried this on?)
Is it a consequence of how Blazor WebAssembly is implemented?
How reliable is this behaviour likely to be? (In future versions of browsers, in future versions of .NET and Blazor WebAssembly?) (Based on the representations made by the Blazor Fiddle site, I believe that it presently uses .NET 6.0.)

The browsers I tried this in were Microsoft Edge (64-bit build 123.0.2420.65) and Mozilla Firefox (version 123.0). Both showed the same behaviour.
